# Cannot connect to AWS RDS DB Instance from EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xyz.cdhtaamn5ynq.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)

I enabled Public Accessible while creating RDS DB Instance. I opened 3306 port in EC2 instance security group. I commented binding-address=localhost in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file. I cannot able to connect RDS through EC2 instance. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your EC2 instance and your RDS instance in the same VPC?

Comment: Yes. Both are in different subnet.

Comment: Does the security group of your EC2 instance have any outgoing rules?

Comment: Thanks Matt. The problem is solved. I opened traffic for EC2 instance from DB instance security group.

Comment: Its always security groups, and if it isnt, it's probably a NACL. But if the problem was the NACL, you'd know to check the SG first :)

Comment: This answer has your question covered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030692/wordpress-and-phpmyadmin-cannot-open-a-rds-database?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Hope this help to resolve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030692/wordpress-and-phpmyadmin-cannot-open-a-rds-database?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @BiswajitMohanty Thanks for response. I solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Even with publicly available checked -- your RDS instance is still launched into a Security Group.  I would look at the inbound rules on this security group to ensure that traffic is allowed from your ec2 instance.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I opened traffic for an EC2 instance from DB instance security group.