# Wordpress and phpMyAdmin cannot open a RDS database

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, mariadb, amazon-rds

I created a WordPress multisite on an EC2 using CentOS 7 with MariaDB.

Amazingly it works.

I followed the instructions [here](https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/using-amazon-rds-with-your-wordpress-installation/)
to upload the database 
using MySQL from a command line I can attach to and see the RDS database.

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW databases;

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| WPDB01             |
| information_schema |
| innodb             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

MariaDB [(none)]> select User, Host from mysql.user;

```
+-----------------+-----------+
| User            | Host      |
+-----------------+-----------+
| WordPressAbuser | %         |
| WordPressUser   | %         |
| rdsadmin        | localhost |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

So I know the ports are open and the database is there.

But changing localhost inside of `wp-config.php` to `mymariadb.xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Does not work" does not work for us.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Your EC2 security group is attached to RDS security group?

[check the below image of rds security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHSzE.png)

Your RDS should have a new separate security group and in the source, you have to add ec2 security group.

that rds security group should be attached to you rds instance 
the ec2 security group should attach to the corresponding ec2 instance

then try to connect